# How to properly use javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to draw a simple dog house in canvas 2d in javascript.

First I was doing all in function main... but now I'm trying to use other functions to call them, but it doesn't seem to work, it only shows the blue background

Any help?

```
function box(){
  let house = new Path2D();
  house.moveTo(460, 455);
  house.lineTo(430, 410);
  house.lineTo(400, 455);
  house.fillRect(400, 450, 60, 50);
  return house;
}

function prism(){
  let roof = new Path2D();
  roof.moveTo(460, 455);
  roof.lineTo(430, 410);
  roof.lineTo(400, 455);
  return roof;
}

function doghouse(background){

  let house_box = box(); //house
  let house_prism = prism(); //roof

  background.strokeStyle="black";

  background.fillStyle = "red";
  background.fill(house_box); background.stroke(house_box);
  background.fillStyle = "red";
  background.fill(house_prism); background.stroke(house_prism);

}


function main() {
  let background = document
          .getElementById("acanvas")
          .getContext("2d");
  background.fillStyle = "#89cff0";
  background.fillRect(0,0,1024,1024);

  doghouse(background);

}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you calling `main()` anywhere? What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Are you getting errors? And how do you call `main`?

Comment: main is being called in html file <body onload="main();">

Comment: It only displays the blue background, so main function is running

Comment: One issue I noticed is that the `Path2D` object does not have the `fillRect` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D